# Что делать, если хочешь включить hyper-v, но в компонентах Windows его нет?

Tags: windows, hyper-v, amd, виртуальная-машина

[image: Фотография, на которой открыты компоненты Windows]

Что делать??????????????????????????????????????

Comment: А редакция windows какая? вроде hyper v только начиная с про версии в home hyper-v вроде нет

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/reference/hyper-v-requirements

Comment: Мне кажется, @EvgeniyZ дал ссылку на полноценный ответ. Поэтому лишь дополню его: практика показала, что гипервизоры других производителей могут эффективнее использовать ресурсы оперативной памяти в среде Windows 10, нежели родной Hyper-V.